# Jackson 2 и Конвертация java объекта в json

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Добрый день. Пытаюсь отправить объект из спринг контроллера на ангуляр и на вьюшку:

pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>LT</groupId>
<artifactId>LT</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.core>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.core>
    <spring.mvc>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <postgresVersion>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresVersion>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    <spring.securiry>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.securiry>
    <mail.version>1.4</mail.version>
    <postgres.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgres.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.securiry}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SPRING -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>LT</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Контролллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMessage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMessage() throws JsonProcessingException {
   //ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    //String json = ow.writeValueAsString("Hello World!!");
    //return json;
    return "Hello World!!";
}
```

}

ангуляр-сервис:

```js
function userService(http) {

var service = {};

service.getAllRoles = function () {
    console.log("Getting Message from back-end");
    return http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/user/getMessage'
    })
};

    return service;
}

userApp.service('userService', ['$http', userService]);
```

ангуляр-контроллер

```js
function userController($scope, $http, userService) {

   userService.getAllRoles().success(function (data) {
    $scope.stroka = data;
    console.log(data);
}, function error() {
    console.log("error");
});
}

userApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$http', 'userService',     userController]);
```

в результате при загрузке страницы получаю:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at xc (angular.min.js:16)
at dc (angular.min.js:91)
at angular.min.js:92
at q (angular.min.js:7)
at gd (angular.min.js:92)
at f (angular.min.js:94)
at angular.min.js:131
at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
```

Если в контроллере отправлять объект таким образом

```
 ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
 String json = ow.writeValueAsString("Hello World!!");
 return json;
```

всё работает, но если отправлять просто джава объект - ошибка. Раньше, перед отправкой, я никаких манипуляций с джава объектами не делал, и всё работало (я считал что либа jackson находится в класспассе и она автоматов конвертировала всё в json), но сейчас нет. Может кто-то подсказать, что нужно поменять чтоб объекты автоматический конвертировались в json?

**UPD** Не понимаю почему, но такая проблема возникает только когда пытаюсь отправить символьную строку.. При попытке отправить сущность, или даже строку вида "12345" всё работает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Начнем с трейса на стороне js.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Браузер явно указывает, что первый символ в полученной строке - `H`, и парсеру JSON это не нравится. Потому что [спецификация JSON](http://www.json.org/) предусматривает соблюдение определенного синтаксиса. И все текстовые строки, кроме `true`, `false` и `null` согласно ей должны быть завернуты в двойные кавычки.

Обратите внимание, что когда вы возвращаете из контроллера просто строку

```
return "Hello World!!";
```

тело HTTP-ответа будет выглядеть так:

```
Hello World!!
```

Если же вы прогоните строчку через `ow.writeValueAsString`, то Jackson преобразует исходное значение в валидное JSON-выражение, и HTTP-ответ уже будет содержать другую строку:

```
"Hello World!!"
```

Comment: То есть, строка должна быть в виде чего-то такого? "\"Hello World!!\"";